# Error message Issues with uploading a file with Ajax call in the JS file getting C:\\fakepath\\(filename)

Tags: javascript, jquery, c, ajax

Im trying to upload a file to the server using an Ajax script and getting a fake path included in the file path name how can I fix it to upload the file from the current working directory specifying the selected file name.

```
function simlib_edit_file_upload(port, editor, __form, __box) {
    editor.text('');

    if (!(__box === undefined)) {
        alert_show(__box, "Uploading file, please wait...");
    }

    // Disable all buttons
    $('.button').prop('disabled', true);

    $.ajax({
        url: __form.action + '?port=' + port,
        type: 'POST',
        data: new FormData(__form),
        processData: false,
        context: $('body'),
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        traditional: true,
        success: function(data) {               

            if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Chrome')) {
                var catchFile = $("__form").val().replace(/C:\\fakepath\\/i, '');
            }
            else {
                var catchFile = $("__form").val();
            }
            editor.text(data);
        },
        error: function(xhr, type) {
            alert_show(__box, 'Ajax error!')
        },
        complete: function(xhr, status) {
            if (!(__box === undefined)) {
                alert_hide(__box);
            }
            // Reenable all buttons
            $('.button').prop('disabled', false);
        }
    });
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

Comment: ERROR: simrpc_open() failed!

Comment: I've never heard of that function, and neither has Google.

Comment: Is it something in your C code on the server?

Comment: Please explain how and where you view this error. Also, have you looked at the request and response details in the firefox debugger (F12-network tab)?